# Python - file cannot be found

Tags: python

I have the file named fileimporter.py in my project and when run the project, it raises the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\python\project\samples\clientlogin_example.py", line 54, in <module>
    CSVImporter(ft_client).importFile("data.csv")
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\fusiontables\fileimport\fileimporter.py", line 39, in importFile
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1S762e1A1XD1R97hy2LDgokzWo4fw_YWgUPbptlc'
```

In the top of my class I have the line below that corresponds with the structure of the project:

```
from project.fileimport.fileimporter import CSVImporter
```

The problem is, I cannot find the path "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\" and even if I delete that file or try to fix it or clean and rebuild the project the same error continue to be raised.

It seems to be a cache file because I have deleted the line where the error happens, but nothing is changed in the console...

Would anybody know how I could find that path??

thank you

Comment: I think your problem might be related to not quoting what appears to be a bitcoin address. If you don't quote that, CSV importers will think it is an integer. With regards to finding your file, I've had good luck on windows with [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/).

Comment: thanks @NickODell...Actually I can remove the line that is generating the error because I do not need it anymore. However, if I change the file from project.fileimport.fileimporter in my project not happens...unfortunately I have to use Windows in this moment...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a left over `pyc` file. e.g.:

```
$ echo "def f(): raise Exception('footastic')" > foo.py
$ python -c "import foo"
$ python -c "import foo; foo.f()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 1, in f
    def f(): raise Exception('footastic')
Exception: footastic
```

Now lets remove `foo.py` and try this again:

```
$ rm foo.py
$ python -c "import foo"
$ python -c "import foo; foo.f()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 1, in f
Exception: footastic
```

Removing the left over `foo.pyc` brings it back to normal:

```
$ rm foo.pyc
$ python -c "import foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo
```

Comment: thank you @bikeshedder...I am using Windows and I did not notice any ".pyc" in that file...